# Custom Taxonomy dentro de outra Custom Taxonomy em WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomia

Estou precisando criar a seguinte hierarquia dentro do admin do WordPress:

**Categoria -> Linha de Produto -> Produto**

Um produto pertence a uma linha que por sua vez pertence a uma categoria.

Pensei em criar uma Custom Taxonomy para Categorias, uma para Linhas.
Populá-las com os dados necessários.

O que eu preciso saber se é possível, é quando for criar um produto (post), se há alguma maneira de puxar para dentro de um select as categorias criadas e as linhas criadas para inserir no produto.

Existe essa possibilidade?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer os produtos como custom posts e criar as taxomonias e os termos próprios pra ele.

EX:

Categoria -> subcategoria -> post

Categoria -> linha de produto -> produto

As duas correndo em paralelo e sem precisar modificar nada na hora de cadastrar o produto, ja que ele vai responder aos suas próprias categorias e termos.

Pra criar o custom do que você precisa coloque isso no functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'type_post_produto');
function type_post_produto() { 
            $labels = array(
                'name' => _x('Produto', 'post type general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Produto', 'post type singular name'),
                'add_new' => _x('Adicionar Novo Produto', 'Novo Produto'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Novo Produto'),
                'edit_item' => __('Editar Produto'),
                'new_item' => __('Novo Produto'),
                'view_item' => __('Ver Produto'),
                'search_items' => __('Procurar Produto'),
                'not_found' =>  __('Nenhum registro encontrado'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nenhum registro encontrado na lixeira'),
                'parent_item_colon' => '',
                'menu_name' => 'Produtos'
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'public_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,      
                'query_var' => true,
                'taxonomies' => array( 'Categoria' ),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'produto'),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'menu_position' => null, 
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
            );

        register_post_type( 'produtos' , $args );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        }
```

Com isso você só vai precisar criar as hierarquias de categorias de produto e criar loopings customizados para recuperar os "produtos".